# Selecting an option and automatically selecting by default multi-options from another forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm very bad at explaining myself. So i'm going to set what i'm looking for by steps.

1. First select what you want.
2. In the background, when you select the additional options which for example is organize 1 bedroom and 1 bathroom to grab that and by default select it to the other forms. So when you insert know my price, it shows you the cost for weekly, biweekly, and monthly services.

I'm not sure what to look for since I myself can't even explain it directly. I Hope the example i gave helped you understand what i'm looking for?

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
   
      <hr>
      
      <!--Weekly form-->
      
    <legend>On going service</legend>
      <select >
      <option value="">Select day of the week</option>
      <option value="10">Monday</option>
      <option value="10">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="10">Wednesday</option>
       <option value="10">Thursday</option>
      <option value="10">Friday</option>
      </select>
      

      
      <select>
      <option value="">Organize a:</option>
      <option value="10">1 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="20">2 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="30">2 bedroom 2 bathroom home</option>
      </select>
         
     </fieldset>
          
          <div style="display:none;">
          
      <hr>     
      
      <!--Biweekly form-->
      
      <fieldset>
    <legend>Biweekly</legend>
      <select >
      <option value="">Select day of the week</option>
      <option value="100">Monday</option>
      <option value="100">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="100">Wednesday</option>
       <option value="100">Thursday</option>
      <option value="100">Friday</option>
      </select>

      
      <select>
      <option value="">Organize a:</option>
      <option value="100">1 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="200">2 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="300">2 bedroom 2 bathroom home</option>
      </select>
      </fieldset>
      
      
        
      <hr>
      
      <!-- Monthly form-->
      
      <fieldset>
    <legend>Monthly</legend>
      <select >
      <option value="">Select day of the week</option>
      <option value="1000">Monday</option>
      <option value="1000">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="1000">Wednesday</option>
       <option value="1000">Thursday</option>
      <option value="1000">Friday</option>
      </select>

      
      <select>
      <option value="">Organize a:</option>
      <option value="1000">1 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="2000">2 bedroom 1 bathroom home</option>
      <option value="3000">2 bedroom 2 bathroom home</option>
      </select>
      </fieldset>
      </div>
      
      <!--After everything is selcted-->
      
      <button class="button">Book weekly</button> <div align="center">$PRICE</div>
      <br>
      <button class="button">Book biweekly</button> <div align="center">$PRICE</div>
      <br>
      <button class="button">Book monthly</button> <div align="center">$PRICE</div>
```

Comment: So you want to show different forms based on the selections made in the dropdowns?

Comment: it seems you'd like automatically select same selection of other forms when first form is selected? is it correct?

Comment: @Sphinx yes that is correct, since only one form will show and be selected. I don't want clients to go to multiple forms to get their price. I want them to put what they need and then provide them the prices all at once. Without any extra effort.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Not show because each form will have the same questions but will have different prices due to one being a weekly services, another being a biweekly service and lastly a monthly service.

Comment: you can bind `change` event for first `<select class="room-type">`, then in the handler of the event, change the value for `<select  class="other-room-type">`